# Explicit formula for the linear non homogeneous recurrence relation I found

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, relations

After some observations, I have figured out a recurrent pattern inside a sequence of numbers that looks like $\{0, 3, 9, 18, 30, 45, \ldots\}$.
The recurrence formula is the following:
\begin{align*}
A_n = A_{n-1} + 3n,  && A_0 = 0
\end{align*}
After I solve it, by unifying the solution for the homogeneous part and the one for the particular one, I obtain that $A_n = 3n(n-1)/2$, which as it can be seen describes the sequence $\{0, 0, 3, 9, 18, 30, \ldots\}$ which is not the same as the sequence it should refer to. Please if anyone can help, it would be really thanked.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two sequences differ only by a shift in indices. If you replace $n$ by $n+1$ you will get:
$$A_n=3\cdot\frac{(n+1)((n+1)-1)}{2}=3\cdot\frac{n(n+1)}{2}.$$
This is what you wanted.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that but I don’t know where it comes from.

Comment: [+1] But you should recall that you use the (classical) formula for the sum of the first $n$ integers in order that Alejandro understands.

Comment: I have tried to find an invertible function that describes this sequence that I came up with after thinking in my head about a visual way to come up with the relation between x’s and y’s, however it looks to me that I cannot invert it in any case. I also found another valid function that explains the sequence which is this one : f(x) =3*( summation symbol(from i:1 to x) of i ) Please I would be interested in a way to find an invertible function that explains this sequence. I want it to use it for an encryption project I’m myself working on

Comment: @JeanMarie Sorry, I’m new to this platform so forgive me If I’m doing things wrong in the chat. What do you exactly mean? Could you explain deeper

Comment: @Alejandro From your question I assumed that you got some understanding to come to the formula $3n(n-1)/2$ and only needed the correction to make it work properly. If this is not the case I am a bit lost on what you exactly need. It's certainly true that $A_n=3\cdot\frac{n(n+1)}{2}=3\sum_{i=1}^ni=f(n)$ - here is a [German reference](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gau%C3%9Fsche_Summenformel). At least for $x=A_n\geq\frac{1}{2}$ it is possible to invert this function: $n=f^{-1}(x)=(-3+\sqrt{9+24x})/6$. But as I see it that's not what you originally asked. Though: if it helped I am glad.

Comment: @ThomasPreu Yes, I am conscious of the work I did to get to all the formulas exposed above. On the other hand, thanks a lot for providing me with an inverse formula valid for input values greater than a half. This has solved my problems, however , I would love to find out if possible, how you managed to find the inverse formula. Thanks again

Comment: @Alejandro My comment was "targetting" Thomas.

Comment: @Alejandro solve an equation for $n$ depending on the parameter $x$: solve $x=3\cdot\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\Leftrightarrow 0=\frac{3}{2}n^2+\frac{3}{2}n-x\Leftrightarrow 0=n^2+n-\frac23x$. You can use [the solution formula for quadratic equations](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula) to solve this equation. You get two solutions $n_{1,2}=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{1-\frac83x}}{2}=\frac{-3\pm\sqrt{9-24x}}{6}$. The solution with the "$+$", gives you the inverse for $x\geq\frac12$.